# How to bind lookup field value in canvas app newform?

Tags: reactjs, office365, sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I need to bind a lookup field value in powerapp new form. the lookup field value id should be pass through url or any other method. my requirement is to set the new form lookup field named 'Company' , binding the lookup field with the current site collection name

Comment: did you looked into [this article](https://wonderlaura.com/2017/08/16/powerapps-set-sharepoint-lookup-field/) Also could you share your query/connection. I mean how are you fetching your data from sharepoint.